# Unsubscribe from a repo using Github App on Slack

Tags: github, slack-commands

The Github App on Slack let's you subscribe to notifications for a repository using the `/github subscribe organization/repository` command.
I want to know how to undo this, or how do I unsubscribe from the org/repo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[documentation](https://github.com/integrations/slack#subscribing-and-unsubscribing)

The `/github` slash command also supports unsubscribe. To unsubscribe to notifications from a repository, use `/github unsubscribe <organization>/<repository>`